# People keep voting down my questions

Tags: discussion, downvotes

What is the real purpose of voting down questions and answers? I thought it was a way of saying that the question is not clear, doesn't include own work to try to fix the problem, etc.

Recently a few of my questions have been voted down, with no explanation, even though my questions follow the rules, provide details, and are on topic. And now I am being warned about being banned from posting questions, answers, or comments. What am I supposed to do about this?

Comment: Do you have recent deleted questions? I only see _one_ recent one that has a single downvote...

Comment: There are 13 deleted questions, only one recent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248499/difference-between-building-a-component-with-the-ionic-cli-vs-angular-cli

Comment: The one Zoe linked is quite broad. The other recent question is basically asking for a library. They're not as on-topic as you might think.

Comment: Write better questions? Seriously, what answer do you expect us to give without any specific examples? "I thought it was a way of saying that the question is not clear, doesn't include own work to try to fix the problem, etc" Yes. Or that the question is too broad, off-topic, lacking basic research, very poor formatting, cannot be reproduced, asking for opinions etc etc. There are a lot of things that can make a question bad.

Comment: All you can do is try to improve your question-asking ability. There's really not that much more to it. You can also try answering other questions to learn more about what makes a good question worth answering and which questions are rather useless and should be downvoted. Visit help section and study posts on Meta that discuss question quality. You will learn a lot from this.

Comment: “And now I am being warned about being banned from posting questions, answers, or comments. What am I supposed to do about this?” - **Stop** deleting your questions would be a great start

Comment: Ranking of search results; good stuff needs to get priority, unwanted stuff needs to get less priority. The whole purpose of a knowledge base is to provide you with useful content, easily. Quality rating and ordering needs to happen to achieve that, there is no other way around it. What tends to be lost on people is generally that all we do is tailored towards being able to *find* information, not to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I know what makes a bad question, but the reason I am asking, is because I have seen some of the _worst_ (in more than one way) questions have many votes, comments, and answers, and then my questions that are sincere and not as bad as those ones (I can't remember any specific ones), get hated on. There have been a few of my questions that are too broad or don't _show_ my effort, but I think that if someone has a question, you shouldn't hate on there question even if it is slightly bad.

Comment: @SecurityHound The reasons why I deleted some of my questions was because they were closed, voted down a ton, or for some other reason, and so it was pointless to leave them there...

Comment: "I think that if someone has a question, you shouldn't hate on there question" Downvotes aren't hateful. As you yourself said in the question, they're merely a way of marking a question as not clear, not useful, or not showing enough research effort. They're not personal. And if you yourself admit that some of your questions fall into those categories, it shouldn't be a surprise that they get downvoted, should it?

Comment: @JacobHornbeck: Your feelings about downvotes are quite common, but after more than a decade of experience here nobody has come up yet with a better way to score question and answer content for quality.

Comment: @JacobHornbeck - So as a result of you deleting your questions, instead of editing them to address the reason they were downvoted and/or closed, you are not closer towards the threshold to be question banned.

Comment: @F1Krazy One downvote isn't hating on a question, but when people keep downvoting it, it just seems like people are just doing it for fun, and that is what I was talking about when I said "hate on [it]".

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk What it should be is just use a special flag type that will let the author know that it has been flagged for being off topic, unclear, not showing solution attempts, etc. They could also make it where people can only downvote if they leave a comment that states why they downvoted.

Comment: @JacobHornbeck: That does nothing at all for the site, that's just tries to spare the feelings of the person posting the question at the expense of providing honest public assessment of the quality of the question. That would be a very bad idea.

Comment: @F1Krazy And as an example, this question/discussion. It is now -20 votes. It just seems like people see that it is negative votes, so they make it more negative... for fun (I'm not saying that is the case, that is just what it makes me think).

Comment: What does it matter to you if it's +1, -1, -20, or -197? The more negative it is the more people disagree with your position. Do you not want to know?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk How would it "do nothing at all for the site". It tells the author that they need to fix there question, and if they don't, then they could close it or something. And if people could only downvote if the post a comment explaining _why_ they did, that would help the author of the question know how to better fix their question.

Comment: Positive = Useful, Negative = Bad. Numbers just represents how many people think that way. Also downvoting on meta is different than the actual site.

Comment: >90% of authors of bad questions *never* improve their questions. To refrain from downvoting them would doom the site to mediocrity.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Ok, that makes sense. What doesn't make sense... this is supposed to be a website where developers can ask questions and get answers, but if questions that some people think are "bad" get voted down so much that almost nobody will see it (or if it gets closed), how are they supposed to get an answer.

Comment: [Here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74724950/display-ionic-app-in-web-browser-with-specified-styling) of what I am talking about in general. 3 downvotes, but no comments saying what is wrong. 2 votes for closing, but neither _actually_ apply. My question is on topic, I show that I have done work to try to solve it on my own, etc.

Comment: @JacobHornbeck whether something is good quality or not or is on-topic or not is not up to you, your peers decide that. I'll meet you half-way though, there is a bit of an unfortunate tendency to just get questions closed and not caring all that much about the correct closure reason to be applied. It is one of the many responses people have to there just being too much content to have to process with what little hands are left over to do the work. That does not mean that the question did not deserve to be closed, it just means people are being sloppy with the bookkeeping.

Comment: “is because I have seen some of the worst (in more than one way) questions have many votes” - So have you provided feedback to these questions and cast a downvote?

Comment: "This is supposed to be a website where developers can ask questions and get answers" It is. It is not, however, a website where developers necessarily get answers *to the questions they asked for the specific purpose of getting a specific piece of code to run*. Instead - to the extent that there is community here - the site exists to *share* questions that phrase *important* difficulties in ways that invite an answer, so that *many* developers can *learn and understand* around that difficulty.

Answer (score 8):

> What is the real purpose of voting down questions and answers?

To mark content that is of low quality. Specifically, to indicate that a question is unclear (which is also a reason to close questions), not useful (e.g.: asks a question that others would not ask; or falls afoul of other question-closing reasons) or demonstrates a [lack of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For answers, that they are not useful (in particular because they are not correct, or do not provide adequate explanation for someone who would have the question).

In other words, exactly what the pop-ups tell you.

> I thought it was a way of saying that the question is not clear, doesn't include own work to try to fix the problem, etc.

Yes, you understand more or less correctly.

> Recently a few of my questions have been voted down, with no explanation

No explanation is owed, and no explanation will be expected in the future. This is [extremely well-tread ground on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+explain+downvote); the canonical explanation is [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/).

> even though my questions follow the rules, provide details, and are on topic.

These are **nowhere near** sufficient to meet the requirements described above.

In particular, if you are trying to figure out a problem in your code - i.e., to do *debugging* - then do not simply post the code and a question on Stack Overflow. That is not the kind of "detail" we want. We want a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - by the time you have created a *proper* MRE, **you will not have a debugging question any more**. Make sure to [attempt your own debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and *understand* the problem - make sure you **know what you expect the program to do, at every step**, and carefully check to see **where that expectation is not met**. Then create code that **only, and directly** demonstrates that problem.

> And now I am being warned about being banned from posting questions, answers, or comments. What am I supposed to do about this?

Read the [advice for those who were already banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/), and be proactive. (In particular, beware that the score of deleted questions still counts against you for a ban, and deleting questions prevents them from getting upvoted.) Look at existing new questions that get upvoted, to understand what they have in common. Improve your own questions accordingly.

---

Considering your most recently asked question as a case study:

> I have an Ionic app that I am working on. I have an Android device that I can test it on, but I do not have a way to test my app on iOS. Is it possible to test my app (visually only, not native functionality) for iOS without having a physical iOS device?

This primarily suggests a **lack of research**. I have *absolutely no idea* what Ionic even is; but when I saw this question, my *gut instinct* was to try typing `test ionic app without device` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=test+ionic+app+without+device). When I try this, I immediately see not just useful links, but even full Youtube tutorials with promising titles like "Ionic 5 Tutorial #33 - Test Ionic App On Android Emulator". I assume this doesn't meet your exact requirements, but it suggests that not a lot of refinement would be required to get you on your way.

Another issue here is that Stack Overflow does not provide tech support. Did you consider first looking for an Ionic-specific support forum, for example?

And above all else, keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. In particular, this entails that questions that you post here *are not* there specifically so that we can help you get your code working, but so that *you can contribute to a knowledge base*. It also means writing questions that look like they belong in a FAQ, not on a discussion forum.

Telling us that you "ran into many problems", or that you "Tried for days to fix it, but nothing worked" is **actively counterproductive**. First off, we can't see **what you tried, or what the problems were**. Second, it implies multiple separate questions about separate problems.

Comment: That part that you say "suggests a lack of research" is called a question introduction. The question wizard tells you to do it. I introduce my question, then give more details. I tried searching for it, in many different ways, and everything was almost the same or was the same as what you found. None of it helped for my question

Comment: "That part that you say "suggests a lack of research" is called a question introduction. The question wizard tells you to do it. I introduce my question, then give more details." You are supposed to do the research **before** asking the question. "I tried searching for it, in many different ways, and everything was almost the same or was the same as what you found." Then you should say **in the question, specifically** what you searched for, what you found, and why it is not relevant.

Comment: You aren't getting it. I **did** the research, but for the question, you state your question, then provide details (not saying that you ask the question and then add details later, after you've done research, just after the part where you state your question).

Comment: Also, when I spend hours and hours searching for a solution before I ask a question here on SO, I can't remember any specific searches or results. Sometimes I can remember small details of the searches and results, and when I do, I put them in my questions.

Comment: Doing the research is not the issue. **Showing** the research is the issue. It's not that we care how much time you put into it. We care that the question is **properly focused**, not a duplicate, and **clear** (i.e., uses terminology that makes sense for the question, shows what is wrong, and pre-empts the question of "why not just try *this* web search?") **because of** the research that was put in.